# changing date format before insertion to database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm uploading an excel file to a server and then inserting its rows and columns into a database. I'm doing it line by line but I have a problem with datetime. After inserting 146 rows of data I get an error which reads:

***The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.***

The problem is its the date. In the excel files the dates are formatted dd/mm/yyyy but the the database is taking them as being mm/dd/yyyy so when the date does past the 12th I get the out-of-range errror. I dont want to change my excel files so is there an option I can change on the database (MS SQL-server) or do I have to use c# code which can convert them before they get inserted... Thanks...

Comment: parameterised queries with `DateTime` datatype would be a good thing

Answer (score 2):

If you know the format coming from Excel, you are best parsing the string to a DateTime in C# with a specific IFormatterProvider.

The problem here is there is no culture information on the string coming from Excel, so the conversion to a DateTime can only take into account the culture of the database - in this case a format that reverses the month and day. This will mean that dates outside the range (as in your case) or ambiguous dates will never parse correctly.

In C# code you are able to specify a culture that implements `IFormatterProvider`, en-GB has the date format of the Excel dates you specify. The example in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs) shows how to do this. My example briefing shows how to convert a string with an en-GB date format into a `DateTime` that is culture agnostic:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
var date = DateTime.Parse("13/12/2011", culture);
```

SQL has the same problem with culture. A string representation of any culture-sensitive data will always lose the current culture. When converting that data you need to specify the culture if it differs from the server.

You can do this in SQL and hard-code the format of the string you are trying to convert (103 represents en-GB date formats dd/mm/yyyy):

```
declare @datestring varchar(10) = '13/12/2011' --13th December
-- 103 is the format code for UK dates with full yyyy century.
select convert(date, @datestring, 103) --gives 2011-12-13

declare @datestring2 varchar(10) = '05/04/2011' --5th April, ambiguous date.
select convert(date, @datestring2, 103) --gives 2011-04-05
```

[Convert / cast format codes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

It is also worth noting that this will also correctly convert ambiguous dates such as 05/04/2011, which would reverse the month/day if the culture wasn't known.

For example, if you tried to convert the UK 5th April 2011 into a US date without telling the parser what the format is, you will get 4th May 2011 as output - reversing the month and day.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this before inserting with T-SQL :

```
set dateformat dmy
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189491.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First parse your excel datetime to C# datetime object and format the datetime object as let's say

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(drExcel["dateofExcel"]);
drDB["DateTime"] = dt.ToString("s");
```

hopefully it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do in database as well probably try to write a stored procedure that inserts your data to database using your excelsheet.

User below mentioned TSQL code in your SP and that will work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC
AS
-- Do some operation
    SET DATEFORMAT ydm;

    insert into @dates
    select '2008-09-01','2008-09-01'

END
```

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT ydm; is the key and does the formatting in your case you can set it to mdy. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259188%28v=sql.80%29.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it in c#.
Try something like this:

```
String excelDate = ...
String[] dateParts = excelDate.Split('/');
String sqlDate = dateParts[1] + "/" + dateParts[0] + "/" + dateParts[2];
...
```